# How to create a NHibernate query with sub select, group by and three values

Tags: nhibernate

I have two entity classes/tables where I store events. Now I want to create a statistic which is grouped by start time, end time and interval.

The SQL looks like this:

```
select Value, Block, Count(*) as Count from 
    (select p.Value, DATEDIFF(s, Convert(datetime2, '2022-03-01 10:00:00', 120), e.Timestamp) / 86400 as Block
        from SystemEventProperties p inner join SystemEvents e on p.EventId = e.Id
        where e.Timestamp >= Convert(datetime2, '2022-03-01 10:00:00', 120)
        AND e.Timestamp <= Convert(datetime2, '2023-03-30 10:00:00', 120)
        AND p.Name = 'Chute' 
        AND e.Name = 'ArticleSorted'
        ) as innerTmp
group by Value, Block
order by Value, Block
```

The value 86400 in this example is the interval.

I can't get NHibernate to give me the result as it does in SQL Management Studio.

[image: Query result]

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: what is the NHibernate query and how does the result differ?